# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.' occurs

Tags: python, error-handling

When I run the code, permission error occurs. How can I fix it? Thanks.
Error message is **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'**

```
csv_files = glob.glob('../3_output/*.csv')

for csv_file in csv_files:
  calcValidation(csv_file)
```

I tried to extract csv file path and put it to a function to get results. I was expecting to get the function run and get the output.